# sqlalchemy Stored Procedure with Output

Tags: python, stored-procedures, parameters, sqlalchemy, output-parameter

I want to call a stored procedure and receive the output parameter in python. I am using sqlAlchemy and can use parameters but do not know how to have the output be read into a variable. I understand that there is a outParam() attribute in sqlAlchemy, but I have not found a useful example.

Here is a simple SQL code for testing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
    @numOne int,
    @numTwo int,
    @numOut int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @numOut = @numOne + @numTwo

END
```

And simple python:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
outParam = 0
result = engine.execute('Test ? ,?, ? OUTPUT', [1, 2, outParam])
```

outParam is still 0. I have tried modifying it with:

```
outParam = sqlalchemy.sql.outparam("ret_%d", type_=int)
```

But this produces a "Programming Error." What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy returns a `ResultProxy` object. Try it like this:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
rproxy = engine.execute(...)
result = rproxy.fetchall()
```

`result` should be a `list` of `RowProxy` objects that you can treat like dictionaries, keyed on the column names from the query.

If you are looking for a true `OUT` param, your approach is almost correct. There is just a small error in the first parameter in the call to `sqlalchemy.sql.outparam` (but it is valid Python syntax). It should be like this:

```
outParam = sqlalchemy.sql.outparam("ret_%d" % i, type_=int)
```

Note the change to the first parameter: it just needed a value to substitute into the format string. The first parameter is the `key` value, and most likely `%d` is to be replaced with the column index number (which should be in `i`).

Comment: It's a fine work around that works well, but I am more interested in proper interfacing between SQL and Python

Comment: @DanG If you are specifically looking to make the `outparam` call work, i updated this answer with some info on that. Your approach is almost correct, just a small problem that will only get caught at runtime, and probably only after the query gets passed to the database.