# SqlAlchemy Stored Procedure Returns without executing entire proc

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I'm writing stored procedure for performing an update operation using SQL Server.

The Stored Procedure performs the following high level operations

```
--Print the values before update
SELECT 'Before' as When, x, y, z FROM eod.fn_get_data(@pricingdate)

BEGIN TRAN;
--Logic to update the data

--Print the values after update
SELECT 'After' as When, x, y, z FROM eod.fn_get_data(@pricingdate)

--Based on whether it was a test run or not, commit/rollback the transaction.
IF @Debug = 1
   ROLLBACK TRAN;
ELSE
   COMMIT TRAN;
```

When I execute this stored procedure in SSMS -  EXEC my_stored_proc @pricingdate = '08/17/2023', it updates the data as expected and runs fine.

When I execute the same using SqlAlchemy, it doesn't seem to update the data. Infact, it returns me the data that I print before Update. (SqlAlchemy version - 1.2.18)

So, my logic to updata the data in the stored procedure contains CTEs in the following format

```
WITH cte1 AS
(--LOGIC),
cte2 AS(--LOGIC),
UPDATE t1
SET x = a, y=b
FROM
  cte2 JOIN table1 t1
```

Another thing to note is, if I somehow write a single line UPDATE statement with multiple subqueries after the 'Before Update' SELECT statement, the UPDATE statement gets executed while still returning me the 'Before Update' result.But my team follows a strict guideline to minimize subquery usage, hence I can't go ahead with this approach.

I even tried replacing the CTE with multiple SELECT statements and populating data in temp tables & finally performing update, but that gives similar issue as CTE.

I stumbled upon this SIMILAR issue - https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5492 which points out auto commit related stuff for update CTE, but that's ruled out in my case as I'm already using engine.begin().

The only difference is that OP is directly executing the update CTE as text query while I'm calling it as a part of a larger stored procedure.

Calling code-

```
query = """ EXEC my_stored_proc @pricingdate = ?"""
params = (pricingdate,)
with self._engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(query,params)
```

I tried the following so far -

1. SET NOCOUNT ON; at the top of my stored procedure.
2. I checked and saw a lot of people using callproc() on raw connection cursor object, but unfortunately, I can't use the same. It gives me error saying cursor does not have callproc method.
3. I found this post [SQLAlchemy Executing Stored Procedure with Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558140/sqlalchemy-executing-stored-procedure-with-output) and tried setting autocommit to true as well.

I'm not sure what I can try and how I can fix the issue here. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check out autocommit setting

Comment: Your SP contains multiple SELECT statements so it returns multiple result sets. You are currently only getting the first ('Before') one. See the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets) for suggestions on how to get the other one. And do use `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your SP unless you really need the row counts from your DML statement(s).

Comment: @siggemannen. Since I'm using engine.begin(), as per documentation, it by default has auto commit on. I also used echo = True while creating the engine and I do see auto commits for every proc run. I don't see any errors/warnings.

Comment: Yeah, but do you commit then? Also, you didn't post that info before so how can i know what you're doing :) Pretty sure you're mishandling the transactions

Comment: @siggemannen, I'm new to this codebase, but the other insert/update procs run in production setup & all use the same settings for transaction control.  I have updated the question with some more details on how using CTEs/multi-line selects followed by update is giving me issue but a single UPDATE statement doesn't. I would appreciate your insights on it as well.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, I will go through the same. But I'm more specifically puzzled by why the update statement wouldn't execute here. I removed the SELECT statement and just kept the CTE with logic for updation. I still don't see  updation happening.

Comment: After you run your Python code, try querying the table from SSMS to see if the update really did happen.

Comment: I did. The table is not getting updated except if I write a single update statement with subqueries rather than using CTE/Temp tables. And running the stored proc via SSMS updates it in all cases. I'm not sure what more I should check. I don't want to write a less-readable code just because it works.